# Pygame problem : my player image don't move with scroll

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, pygame-surface

Firts I am french so excuse-me for my english. I have recently discoverd pygame and I love that so decided to create a rpg on pygame and... I have a little problem : with many, many difficulty I made a scrolling system on my pygame's rpg I evn do a system how make sure player's image gets back when he go up, puts himself in profile ...
BUT (a big but) my player's image don't move, the scrolling, move and the player's rect also, I don't know I can solve that so please help me !!!!! The main.py file :

````
from game import Game
from level import *
pygame.init()

lvl = Level()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
pygame.display.set_caption("RPG") 
game = Game()
cam = Camera(1024, 768)
running = True
lvl.generer()
print(game.player.rect)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    cam.update(game.player)
    #print(cam.rect.topleft)
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT) and game.player.rect.x + game.player.rect.width < 1080:
        game.player.move_right()
        lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, cam.x, cam.y)
        #print(game.player.rect.x)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT) and game.player.rect.x > 0:
        game.player.move_left()
        lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, cam.x, cam.y)
        #print(game.player.rect.x)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_DOWN):
        game.player.move_down()
        lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, cam.x, cam.y)
        #screen.scroll(0, -game.player.velocity)
        #print(game.player.rect.y)

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_UP):
        game.player.move_up()
        lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, cam.x, cam.y)
        #screen.scroll(0, game.player.velocity)
        #print(game.player.rect.y)

    #print(cam.rect.x, cam.rect.y)
    #print(cam.rect)

    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)
    print(game.player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             game.pressed[event.key] = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False```
the player.py class : 
```import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.game = game
        self.health = 100
        self.maxHealth = 100
        self.attack = 10
        self.velocity = 10
        self.dimension = (64, 88)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension) 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 512
        self.rect.y = 384
        self.face = [pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_00.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_01.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_02.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_03.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_04.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_05.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_06.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_07.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_08.png"), pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player/sprite_09.png")]


    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_profileLeft/player_profile_left.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension) 

    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_profileRight/player_profile_right.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension) 

    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += self.velocity
        #self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_face/player_face.png")
        #self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension)
        i = 0
        for elt in self.face:
            self.image = self.face[i]
            print("lol")
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension)
            i += 1


    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y -= self.velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assets/player/player_back/player_dos.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, self.dimension)
````

the level.py class :

````
from pygame.locals import *
from player import *

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, widht, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, widht, height)
        self.widht = widht
        self.height = height
        self.topleft = list(self.rect.topleft)
        self.x = self.topleft[0]
        self.y = self.topleft[1]

    def update(self, target):
        self.rect.y = -target.rect.y + int(769 / 2)
        self.rect.x = -target.rect.x + int(1024 / 2)
        self.topleft = list(self.rect.topleft)
        self.x = self.topleft[0]
        self.y = self.topleft[1]
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y, self.widht, self.height)
        #self.rect.topleft_x = self.rect.topleft(0)
        #self.coo = (0, 0)


class Level:
    def __init__(self):
        self.structure = 0


    def generer(self):
        with open("niveau.txt", "r") as fichier:
            structure_niveau = []
            for ligne in fichier:
                ligne_niveau = []
                for sprite in ligne:
                    if sprite != '\n':
                        ligne_niveau.append(sprite)
                structure_niveau.append(ligne_niveau)
            self.structure = structure_niveau

    def afficher(self, fenetre, x, y, camLeftX, camLeftY):
        tailleSprite = 64
        #Camera.__init__(self, x, y)

        grass = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/grass.png").convert_alpha()

        tree = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/tree_grass.png").convert_alpha()

        no_texture = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/no_texture.png")

        num_ligne = 0
        for ligne in self.structure:
            num_case = 0
            for sprite in ligne:
                x = num_case * tailleSprite - camLeftX
                y = num_ligne * tailleSprite - camLeftY
                if sprite == 'G':
                    fenetre.blit(grass, (x, y))

                elif sprite == 'T':
                    fenetre.blit(tree, (x, y))
                    #print(self.x, self.y)

                else:
                    fenetre.blit(no_texture, (x, y))

                num_case += 1
            num_ligne += 1```
````

Comment: Whats the `from game import Game` code look like

Comment: Oh that :`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pygame
from player import Player

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_players = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_players.add(self.player)
        self.pressed = {}

    
    def check_collision(self, sprite, group):
        return pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)` @TheBigKahuna

Comment: So just for holding sprites? Also it would be better if you edited your question and added it, makes it a bit easier.

Comment: So, when you press the up or left key, you want the player image to move on the screen? Do you want the other sprites/background to move too?

Comment: ho I don't put other sprites yet but yers I want the "camera" follow the player

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found the solution but It's making an other problem I'll ask the question on a other post. At x = num_case * tailleSprite - camLeftX and y = num_ligne * tailleSprite - camLeftY on level.py just replace the - by a +